# new Date returned NA value in using datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, datetimepicker

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/2jp7opow/

I want to store like date like this to the DB : yyyy/mm/dd H:mm AM/PM but currently my format is dd/mm/yyyy.. I try to convert it via parsing, it worked strangely. When u select days that is after 12, it return NANANANANA.. why?

```
$(function () {
    $('input').datetimepicker({
        formatTime: 'g:i A',
        format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
        onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
            cms_dateTime = $input.val();
            reformatDate = new Date(cms_dateTime);

            var day = reformatDate.getDate();
            var month = reformatDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var year = reformatDate.getFullYear();
            var hour = reformatDate.getHours();
            var minutes = reformatDate.getMinutes();

            finalDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minutes;
            $('p').text(finalDate);

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `new Date()`? `dp` contains the current time.

Comment: `new Date()` doesn't understand your date format. It understands `MM/DD/YY`. If the day is after 12, that's an incorrect month.

Comment: How does cms_dateTime look like?
Sounds like its a string that cannot be parsed the Date constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dp is the js Date variable.

```
    $(function () {
        $('input').datetimepicker({
            formatTime: 'g:i A',
            format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                var day = dp.getDate();
                var month = dp.getMonth() + 1;
                var year = dp.getFullYear();
                var hour = dp.getHours();
                var dd = "AM";
                if (hour >= 12) {
                    hour -= 12;
                    dd = "PM";
                }
                if (hour == 0) {
                    hour = 12;
                }
                var minutes = dp.getMinutes();

                finalDate = year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minutes + dd;
                $('p').text(finalDate);

            }
        });

    });
```

this prints something like

```
2015/1/23 1:16PM
```